# Which exterior outlet cover is required by NEC?

Tags: electrical, exterior

There are two types of outlet covers used on external outlets. The first type is for damp locations that covers the outlet when it's not in use:

[image: Damp cover]

And the second type is for wet locations that allow the outlet to be sealed while in use:

[image: Wet in-use cover]

How is wet vs damp defined by NEC to differentiate when one cover is required over another?

> NEC 406.8 Receptacles in Damp or Wet Locations: "A receptacle
>   installed outdoors in a location protected from the weather or in
>   other damp locations shall have an enclosure for the receptacle that
>   is weatherproof when the receptacle is covered (attachment plug cap
>   not inserted and receptacle covers closed).". And "receptacles
>   installed in a wet location shall have an enclosure that is
>   weatherproof whether or not the attachment plug cap is inserted."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ## NEC 2008
>
> **406.8 Receptacles in Damp or Wet Locations.**
> **(A) Damp Locations.** ... A receptacle shall be
> considered to be in a location protected from the weather where
> located under roofed open porches, canopies, marquees, and the like,
> and will not be subjected to a beating rain or water runoff. All 15-
> and 20-ampere, 125- and 250-volt nonlocking receptacles shall be a
> listed weather-resistant type.
>
> ## NEC 2008
>
> ### Article 100 Definitions
>
> **Location, Damp.** Locations protected from weather and not subject to saturation with water or other liquids but subject to moderate
> degrees of moisture. Examples of such locations include partially
> protected locations under canopies, marquees, roofed open porches, and
> like locations, and interior locations subject to moderate degrees of
> moisture, such as some basements, some barns, and some coldstorage
> warehouses.
>
> **Location, Dry.** A location not normally subject to dampness or wetness. A location classified as dry may be temporarily subject to
> dampness or wetness, as in the case of a building under construction.
>
> **Location, Wet.** Installations underground or in concrete slabs or masonry in direct contact with the earth; in locations subject to
> saturation with water or other liquids, such as vehicle washing areas;
> and in unprotected locations exposed to weather.

Comment: Thanks Tester. We need to rename you to NEC Lookup Guy. :)

Comment: @BMitch You got to know the rules, if you want to play the game.

Comment: When in doubt use "In-use" covers.

Comment: Ignorance is bliss. I was much happier before I discovered the wire was live.

Comment: Great research Tester! +++

Comment: If I wasn't trying to retire, I'd go buy a new copy of the NEC. Too easy to mooch off from my electrician.  LOL

Comment: Seconding the "always use an in-use cover" advice. Someone will eventually leave an extension cord or Christmas lights plugged in. If not you, then the next person to live there.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing plugged in more than 3 hiours(continious use) a regular weather proof cover is fine for a damp location, bubble covers break off.