# 14/3 to run a small 1650 watt Charbroil electric patio pedestal grill

Tags: electrical

We have a patio outlet that is connected to an interior, 15amp outlet. I want to move the patio outlet about 15 linear feet away from its current location to use for a 1650 watt electric patio grill (a small Charbroil, sold in Walmart/Home Depot).

The circuit is wired with 14/2 cable.

We never use the interior outlet the patio outlet hangs off of so I'd like to just 'junction box' it and put a solid plate over the outlet (it's too close to some decorative dried plants anyhow).

So if I move the outlet and keep to 14/2, can I put the GFI and weatherproof outlet box on the patio and run the electric grill?

Comment: Some photos might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Most consumer appliances are made to plug into a standard 15A outlet.  Your wire (14/2) and breaker (15A) are both suited for this, and your grill uses (1650w / 120v = ) 13.75 Amps.  That all checks out.

GFCI outlets are required in exterior/wet locations, and a weather proof box is a good idea, so you have the right plan there as well.

I think the only other thing you didn't mention is how you are going to run the wire.  If it's outside, run it in the appropriate conduit and use the correct connectors (may depend on exactly how you need to run the wire), and you will be fine.

Comment: Current version of NEC *requires* outdoor receptacles to have a weatherproof cover that protects the receptacle whether or not anything is plugged in (i.e. a "bubble" cover).

Comment: Thanks for that.  I guess that's outdoors anywhere, even under a roof?

Comment: Actually now that I read it (NEC 406.8) it looks like if the receptacle is protected from rain (under a roof or canopy) you can use a cover that is only protective when nothing is in the outlet (i.e. the spring-loaded covers), and an outlet that is exposed to rain needs the bubble-style. See http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15125/which-exterior-outlet-cover-is-required-by-nec for more info.

Comment: While "In-Use" covers may not be required where protected from the weather, it's not a bad idea to install them on all outdoor receptacles.  I don't think the cost difference is much, and installation time is also similar.

Comment: I prefer [these expanding covers](http://m.homedepot.com/p/Taymac-1-Gang-Non-Metallic-Weatherproof-Low-Profile-In-Use-Cover-Gray-ML450G/202266492?cm_mmc=SEM|THD|google|D27E+Electrical&mid=sXM9SbYr7|dm_mtid_8903o6225187_pcrid_70374220117_pkw_ml450g_pmt_p_product__slid_&gclid=CLeIrY_yrsgCFQ4WHwodmPsCFA) over the "bubble" ones. Their less bulky, and more attractive (in my opinion), when not in use.

Comment: I just find those covers don't work unless they are also sheltered.  Maybe I'm buying the cheapies.